# How can I get image url of all the uploaded images from the cloudinary server?

Tags: android, cloudinary

I have successfully uploaded 6 image one by one on Cloudinary. Now I want to get all images URL. How can I get in android mobile client side?

I am using code below.

```
 List<String> imageList = new ArrayList<>();
    Map config = ObjectUtils.asMap(

            "cloud_name", "shank",

            "api_key", "644617911542992",

            "api_secret", "oW3bQk8luOT9UlEkRsH21KoQkxY");

    Cloudinary cloudinary = new Cloudinary(config);

    Api api = cloudinary.api();

    JSONObject outerObject = null;

    String jsonNext = null;

    boolean ifWeHaveMoreResources = true;

    while (ifWeHaveMoreResources) {
        try {

            outerObject = new JSONObject(api.resources(ObjectUtils.asMap("max_results", 10, "next_cursor", jsonNext)));

            if (outerObject.has("next_cursor")) {

                jsonNext = outerObject.get("next_cursor").toString();

                ifWeHaveMoreResources = true;

            } else {

                ifWeHaveMoreResources = false;

            }

            JSONArray jsonArray = outerObject.getJSONArray("resources");

            for (int i = 0, size = jsonArray.length(); i < size; i++) {

                JSONObject objectInArray = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                String public_id = objectInArray.get("public_id").toString();

                String url = objectInArray.get("secure_url").toString();

                imageList.add(url);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

But it gives the exception.

```
java.lang.Exception: Administration API is not supported for mobile applications
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please post your code to check what's wrong with your code

Comment: @SandeepParish I am using code snippet from here [https://support.cloudinary.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360009534411-How-can-i-get-all-files-or-images-from-a-folder]

Comment: it doesn't matter what code snippet you are using, maybe you are missing something or anything else

Comment: @SandeepParish I edited my question. Now you can check my code.

Comment: [Check This](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#client_side_resource_lists), it will help you, let me know if any issue

Comment: It gives something else. when I tried the android code, it gives URL, http://res.cloudinary.com/shank/image/list/logo.json and by this URL, I am getting json which are irrelevant to uploaded image by me.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.Exception: Administration API is not supported for mobile applications

Due to security reasons, Admin API is not available with client SDK like Android.

You should use some kind of proxy server to make this call to Cloudinary (you can use [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) for example)